# Apache Config - How to forward ALL domains to one

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, system-administration

I have a new dedicated server with cPanel/WHM.
I've created 1 account only (I won't need more accounts): maindomain.com

I want ALL domains pointing to my DNSs (more than 50) to be forwarded (NOT redirected) to maindomain.com automatically (without creating entries for each domain)

In httpd.conf I've set `ServerAlias *` for the domain, but to no avail (Yes, I've restarted apache!).

Note that the idea is very similar to what parking sites do. Once you set their DNSs, the site contents are the "same" for every domain.

So, **What should I configure to forward domains to a particular one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non matching domains are forwarded by default to the first one in the configuration files.
So, simply put the virtualhost on top of your config file, or if you're using one file per virtualhost, name it (the file) as 00-something (config files are loaded alphabetically)